# JointJS 2.2.1 styling for Model's port

Tags: javascript, styling, jointjs

previous I was using JointJS 0.9.10 and the attrs for shapes.devs.Model as below works normally

```
attrs: {
      '.inPorts .port-body': { fill: 'red' },
      '.outPorts .port-body': { fill: 'yellow' }
}
```

But when I upgrade JointJS to version 2.2.1, this styling no longer affect to the port of a model. Does this property name got changes on the latest version. Anyone who know this issues please explain to me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent expression in JointJS v2.2.1 would be like this.

```
el.prop({
  ports: {
    groups: {
      'in': {
        attrs: {
          '.port-body': { fill: 'red' }
        }
      },
      'out': {
        attrs: {
          '.port-body': { fill: 'yellow' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Since version `1.0` it is possible to add ports to arbitrary `joint.dia.Element`. The ports are not part of the element's markup and cannot be styled via `attrs` any more.

For more info please see the ports API [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.2/joint.html#dia.Element.ports).